# Scroll button not centered

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to work with bootstrap 4 for my graphic design portfolio, but things aren't going as planned. I have a lot of problems positioning elements, as mx-auto class doesn't always work, neither does align-items-center on parent divs or align-self-center. I do not know what I am doing wrong, but I have tried every combination to make the homepage with the "tahan grafica e fotografia" as showed, but vertically centered. As I couldn't reach the same result with classes, I just moved them with position relative. The result achieved is the same, but in terms of coding I am pretty sure it's not the way I should go. The same happened with the two scrolls, the black and the white one. They are where they are supposed to be, but they have been placed there manually with position relative. Could someone help me? I don't understand what I am doing wrong when using classes. I think one of the problems is that I don't get when I should create a div and when not. For example, I have my container fluid, I have the row, should I place the logo image and the other two texts without a div? If not, why should I create it?  Thank you.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="it">
    <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
      
      <!-- CSS link -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      
      <!-- Fonts -->
      <!-- Karla -->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      
      <!-- CormorantGaramond -->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant+Garamond:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      
      <!-- page title -->
      <title>Tahan</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row home-cont full-height justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-12 homepage align-self-center">
            <div class="logo mx-auto">
              <img src="images/tahan.png" alt="tahan" class="header-title img-fluid">
              <div class="logo-subtext">
                <span class="header-category d-inline-block text-left">
                  grafica
                </span>
                <span class="header-category d-inline-block text-right">
                  fotografia
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a href="#down">
              <img class="scroll mx-auto" id="blackscroll" src="images/iconblack.png">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="container-fluid parts-cont full-height" id="down">
        <div class="row partsofme">
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1 offset-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website17.png" class="object-prayer img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website28.png" class="object-mom img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website26.png" class="object-notebook img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website23.png" class="object-passportven img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website39.png" class="object-fuji img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website32.png" class="object-drawing img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website7.png" class="object-oleum img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website34.png" class="object-cedula img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website1.png" class="object-paintingtable d-none d-lg-block img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website39.png" class="object-fuji d-none d-lg-block img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1 offset-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website6.png" class="object-peluche align-self-center img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website20.png" class="object-postagestamp align-self-center  img-fluid">
          </div>
          
          <div class="partidime col-6 col-lg-6 d-lg-flex text-white ">
            <p>alcu</br>ne p<span id="inserto1">ar</span>ti <span id="inserto2">d</span>i me</p>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website21.png" class="object-sd align-self-center  img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website40.png" class="object-letraset d-none d-lg-block img-fluid align-self-center ">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1 offset-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website2.png" class="object-kodak img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website36.png" class="object-windsorandnewton img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website13.png" class="object-rufa d-none d-lg-block img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website37.png" class="object-bolivar img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website21.png" class="object-sd d-none d-lg-block img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website30.png" class="object-madrid img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website10.png" class="object-pendrive img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website16.png" class="object-magnet img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website15.png" class="object-moleskine img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website41.png" class="object-earphones img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1 offset-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website12.png" class="object-olympus img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website3.png" class="object-hairclip img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website33.png" class="object-collage img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website25.png" class="object-passportit img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website29.png" class="object-story img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website31.png" class="object-polaroid img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website4.png" class="object-brush img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website27.png" class="object-abc img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website8.png" class="object-glue img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/website5.png" class="object-pen img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="text-center justify-content-center d-block">
            <a class="" href="#down2">
              <img class="scroll" id="whitescroll" src="images/iconwhite.png">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <!-- Optional JavaScript before /body -->
      <script src="vendor/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
      <script src="vendor/bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My css:

```
/* Mobile first (phones/tablets, 0 and up) */
    html {
      font-size: 16px; /* valore consigliato 16px, 1rem è uguale a questo valore */
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}


.full-height {
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  position: relative;

}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  top:120px;
  width: 170px;
}

.logo-subtext span {
  width: 48%;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 19px;
  position:relative;
  top:-15px;

}

.scroll{
  max-height: 30px;
  max-width: 30px;
}

#blackscroll{
  position: relative;
  top:200px;
}

.parts-cont {
    background-color: black;
  }
.partsofme {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}


.partidime{
  color: white;
  font-size:110px;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  top:120;

}

#inserto1{
  font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: medium;
  font-size: 140px;
}

#inserto2{
  font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: medium;
  font-size: 110px;
}

.chi-cont{
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block

  }

  .chisono{
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block

    }
.biography p{
  font-family: Karla;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
    }

#cv{
  font-weight: bold;
  }
.
/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .partidime{
    font-size:300px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 230px;
    z-index: 9;
  }


  #inserto1{
    font-size: 300px;
  }

  #inserto2{
    font-size: 300px;
  }


}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .logo {
    width: 260px;
  }

  .full-height{
    max-height: 100vh;
}

  .logo-subtext span {
    width: 48%;
    font-size: 30px;

  }

  .partsofme {
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .partidime{
    font-size:120px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 90px;
    position:static;
  }

  .partidime br {
    display: none;
  }

  #inserto1{
    font-size: 150px;
  }

  #inserto2{
    font-size: 120px;
  }

  .biography p{
    line-height: 30px;
      }

    #blackscroll{
      position: relative;
      top:300px;
      }

    #whitescroll{
        position: relative;
        top:150px;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing the css i am confused how your divs are linked you are using classes and id's on @ keys